# Error shows Object reference not set to an instance of an object?

Tags: c#, .net

I am new to c# and web services...
when i debug the login coding it run on the browser but when enter the login button it shows error Object reference not set to an instance of an object with the source error as below:

```
{

   SqlConnection DBConn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ASPNETDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    try
    {
```

is there any syntax that missing or error connection with database?

Comment: does a connection with name  "ASPNETDBConnectionString" exist in your app/web.Config ?

Comment: do u have checked the connectionstring in web.config file?

Comment: Please show as the complete stacktrace of the error/exception you're getting. Also consider [ask].

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a connection string with `ASPNETDBConnectionString` name, that is why you are getting this error. 
Check it against `null` before using it.

```
if(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ASPNETDBConnectionString"] != null)
         SqlConnection DBConn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ASPNETDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
```

Comment: It helped me,thank you! i've try this and it said that ASPNETDBConnectionString have been added.

Answer (score 0):

1 Add reference on System.Configuration

2 Verify that ASPNETDBConnectionString string connection exist in your App.Config, or your Web.Config

Nota : you must have this section ASPNETDBConnectionString in your file of config

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add 
    name="ASPNETDBConnectionString" 
    connectionString="Data Source=serverName;Initial 
    Catalog=...;Persist Security Info=True;User 
    ID=userName;Password=password"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
  />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: i do like u said..when i debug it there was no error but then after i enter the login, it said that 
"A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)". what's was that problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
firstly add connection string to web config file as follows:

***<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
    </system.web>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="key" connectionString="....." providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    </connectionStrings>
    </configuration>***

then add namespace to .cs page 

> using System.Configuration;


then create a connection string on page as:-
 ***cn = new SqlConnection();
        cn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["key"].ConnectionString;***
```